# How to ping in iOS for Xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am trying to test ping inside a Xamarin Forms project. I figured out I couldnt ping from the pcl and started using dependency services, but I still cant make it work for iOS. I tried to use a SimplePing binding library (https://github.com/pauldotknopf/MonoTouch.SimplePing) but it seems to be outdated. Any tips?

Comment: Do you need ICMP ping or do you just want to know whether the host is reachable?

Comment: @Cheesebaron I need ICMP ping.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that binding does seem out of date. What you might do is get the XCode project from:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SimplePing/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10000716-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

and make your own binding. there is a "Download Code" button at the top of that page. You should only need to bind the header in the Common folder as the rest of what is in that Xcode project is just a UI to test the SimplePing class, and besides the UI part is in swift, which a Xamarin iOS binding project can not work with at this time... but the SimplePing class is in Obj-C so that should be no problem (well binding often has unforeseen problems so don't quote me on that). See Xamarin's guide on creating bindings to iOS libraries:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/

So I would recommend opening the Xcode project in Xcode and then deleting all but the SimplePing.h and SimplePing.m files before building the iOS Static library, the .a file you will eventually include in your Xamarin.iOS binding project.

Then when you use objective sharpie, just point it to the SimplePing.h file to generate the ApiDefinitions.

Answer (score 0):

Also for ObjC binding, make sure you go through ObjC Sharpie, as it can in most cases generate the binding for you via single command line.

Check it out.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-sharpie/